# Did I write the string for "Authorization" in headers correctly?

Tags: rest, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am writing code to add a paypal button to a page. There is this js code:

On the page: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/
The following is written:

Authorizationstringrequired
To make REST API calls, include the bearer token in this header with the Bearer authentication scheme. The value is Bearer  or Basic <client_id:secret>.

I seem to have written everything like that, but I get a 401 error that says about problems with authorization.
Did I write the string for "Authorization" in headers correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it didn't help (I'm testing with http://localhost).

Comment: I found the following statement:
"The command requires the valid user name and password (or API token) in the application to which you want to connect, and it encodes the credentials with base64. In the Authorization Header field, you enter the word "Basic" (which is the Authorization header type), a space, and then the base64-encoded credentials."
But that hasn't helped either.

Comment: More precisely, it helped with the 401 error, but now after applying base64 I get an error 400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client-side/browser code (paypal.Buttons) should never directly call PayPal API endpoints; not under any circumstances. The code in this question should be removed.

Calls to the PayPal API should only be done through a backend/server. See the [standard checkout integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) for an example in node.js , but it can of course be implemented similarly in any other server environment/language.